# Should you make two separate actions or do separate view if you are doing ajax?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am a little confused about the correct approaches towards Ajax in MVC. Say I have an action that returns the same view and same model. The only problem is if it is an Ajax call I need to rearrange the layout of the view. I found that the solution is either I can determine it in the MVC Action us `if (IsAjax)` and return the appropriate View or else I can go to my view and use `@if(IsAjax)` and layout items accordingly.

```
@model MyModels.SomeModel
@if (!IsAjax)
{
arrange this way.....
}
else
{
arrange another way...
}

[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
    ///get the SomeModel via some code here
    if (!Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
     return View2(someModel)
    }
     return View1(someModel)
    }
```

Comment: Kind of a subjective question, but I'd say it's not the view's responsibility to know if the request is an AJAX one or not. I'd perform this logic in the controller action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Determining whether the request is an AJAX request should be the controller's responsibility. Now, whether you want to create a separate action method to handle AJAX requests is up to you, but I think it is the cleaner approach. I'll explain how I handle it in my projects.

First, create a custom attribute to tag the action methods you want to handle the AJAX requests.

```
public class AjaxOnlyAttribute : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValidForRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext, MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        return controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest();
    }
}
```

Now your controller can have separate action methods, one to handle the AJAX request and one to handle the normal request.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
    // Handle the normal request

    return View(model);
}

[ActionName("Details")]
[AllowAnonymous]
[AjaxOnly]
public ActionResult DetailsAjax(int? id)
{
    // Handle the AJAX request

    return PartialView("PartialViewForAJAX", model);
}
```

Note that you have to rename the AJAX action method as you cannot have two action methods with identical names. Tagging this action method with the `[ActionName("Details")]` attribute ensures the method will handle all AJAX requests to the `Details` action method.

This is the cleanest way I have found to separate the controller and view markup for AJAX requests. It not only allows you to keep the code separate in the controller, but it also ensures your view doesn't become messy with separate markup for AJAX requests.

Comment: When I try this, I get _"The current request for action 'DeletePost' ... is ambiguous between the following action methods: DeletePostAjax() / DeletePost()"_ despite their method names being different. Seems like they still need to be different HttpVerbs to coexist.